# React is throwing Error when I use both Router and Context in the same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, compiler-errors, react-router, react-context

I relatively new to React and I'm learning Routers and Context. I have an App.js component that has two routers - Home and About. Apart from Router, there is a banner component that displays date. I stored the date in a context file and tried to wrap the context around the Router in App.js. But I'm getting

> Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to
>   prevent an infinite loop.

Here is App.js structure

```
<DateContext>
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <Banner />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
</DateContext>
```

Is it possible to use both Router and Context in the same component? Or what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you post the code for Home, About and Banner. Seems like one of these components is updating context value

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I think I figured out the problem. I was using multiple return statements inside my component and for some weird reason VS Code did not point out the error. Now it's fixed.